# Maven 3.8 Difference between thread count and forkcount for suitsAndClasses parallelism?

Tags: java, maven, maven-surefire-plugin

I am having a surefire configuration like below

```
<configuration>
 <forkCount>2</forkCount>
 <reuseForks>true</reuseForks>
<perCoreThreadCount>false</perCoreThreadCount>
<parallel>suitesAndClasses</parallel>
</configuration>
```

In a multimodule maven project if I am executing `mvn test -T 5` then how does parallelism work here?

- Will it is that in surefire fork1 5 tests classes will be running in
  parallel from module1 and 5 tests classes will be running in parallel
  from module2 in fork2 assuming no test suites?
- How it will behave when I have test suites? Will it be like suite1 from module1 running in fork1 with 5 test classes running in parallel and in fork2 a different suite from module2 will be running with 5 test classes running in parallel? What happen to those test class which do not belong to any suites?

Versions

- Maven Version 3.8.4
- Surefire version 3.0.0-M6

Comment: take a look at: https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/fork-options-and-parallel-execution.html ?

Comment: I read the link. For `parallel = classes` and `mvn test -T 5`. maven will build and run 5 modules in parallel. During the test phase of each module surefire is getting called and surefire is spawning 2 JVM to distribute the tests. Once all the tests are finished in module surefire fork will be termintated. Again a new surefire fork will be created for executing tests in another module. Only for a module, surefire fork will be reused. Is my understanding correct?